# It is possible to customize the voice of Talkback on Android?

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

Well, I need to make an app with a customized voice for the Talkback, it is possible? I'm gonna record the voice and play on icon, insted of the standard voice. the idea it is not to "read and talk", just talk I'm already know the word.

For example: that is an icon whit label "Settings", when the user select, the custom voice recorded "Settings" will play.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, you can't do this.  Or at least, there is nothing in the accessibility APIs that would support this behavior.  You will have to leverage other portions of the Android OS to make this happen.  You can approach this from two directions:

Option 1: Create your own TTS Engine.

Option 2: Set the content description to "", for items you want a custom announcement for, and do a manual announcement when these items obtain accessibility focus.  Note: I don't endorse this idea, it's atrocious. But, I list it for sake of completeness.